# PHP Mysqli select value for multiple values and show the same for relection

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch multiple values for multiple data i know how to fetch for single data but am new to fetch multiple data

say i want to select mobile number for id 1,2,3 and show the mobile number for same with"," is what i am not able to achive

Expected

1. Select data from Master_table For id"1,2,3"
2. Show the Mobile_number of that particular id(s) as mention below .

Database

```
Master_table
name id  mobile_number
abcd 1   123456789
ssss 2   123456722
sssd 3   123456733
rrrr 4   123453389
iiii 5   123444789
```

PHP

```
$query="SELECT  mobile_number FROM Master_table  WHERE  id='1,2,3'" ;
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    echo $row['mobile_number'];

}
```

expected result is

```
123456789,123456722,123456733
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use MySQL `IN` operator:

Corrected SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT mobile_number FROM Master_table WHERE id IN(1,2,3)";
```

Explanation:

Select `mobile_number` from table where id is either 1, 2 or 3

Difference between `=` and `IN` is that with `=` you can compare only one value.

With `IN` you can compare with a set of values.

So, the flow of SQL is:

```
SELECT mobile_number FROM Master_table WHERE (id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3)
```

Which is similar to:

```
SELECT mobile_number FROM Master_table WHERE id  IN(1,2,3)
```

As per OP's query, following is the updated code:

```
$query="SELECT  mobile_number FROM Master_table WHERE id IN( 1,2,3)" ;
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$mobiles = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
  $mobiles[] = $row['mobile_number'];
    //echo $row['mobile_number'];
}
$mobilesStr = implode(',', $mobiles);
echo $mobilesStr;
```

Comment: say i have id 1,2,3 in select query then it should select the mobile number for all 1,2,3 and show me the all three mobile numbers `123456789`,`123456722`,`123456733`

Comment: gives the error `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C`

Comment: u need to modify your answer with `$query="SELECT  mobile_number FROM Master_table WHERE id IN( '1','2','3')" ;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` clause

```
$query="SELECT  `mobile_number` FROM `Master_table` WHERE  `id` IN (1,2,3) " ;
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    echo $row['mobile_number'];

}
```

> See examples **[HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` keyword like this

```
$query="SELECT  mobile_number FROM Master_table  WHERE  id IN (1,2,3)" ;
```